# AVURLAsset play photo video operation not permitted by AVPlayer

Tags: ios, photokit

I have some URLs for the videos stored in camera rolls. For example:

> file:///var/mobile/Media/PhotoData/Metadata/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0270.medium.MP4

I get photo video url by Photos framework requestAVAssetForVideo:options:resultHandler: interface.

When I run it, using this url play video, I get a completely generic "failure" error message that I have no idea what to do with.

The error is described below:

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed"
>
> UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x170255270 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (1), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}

How do I fix this problem? Appreciate if any suggestion or idea.